# tiny mce wraping div

Tags: html, tinymce

I have some text in tiny_mce

```
<div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. U</div>
```

When I press Enter in editor i get something like this, tiny_mce make 2 divs

```
<div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,</div><div> sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. U</div>
```

I need tag **p** on press Enter, not new div. Is it solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [the FAQ](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_produce_P_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_BR_elements.3F). Default behavior seems to be `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tinymce init setting

```
forced_root_block: 'p',
```